# Creating Generic methods

Tags: c#, generics

I am here wanted to implement some methods that coverts a list of interface references to their respective class type and then return the list is unique in some sense.

Here is the

```
    public bool IsFilesHavingUniqueID(List<IFile> files)
    {
        List<File> _files = files.ConvertAll(x => (File)x).ToList();
        return _files.Distinct().ToList().Count == _files.Count; 
    }

    public bool IsTablesHavingUniqueID(List<ITable> tables)
    {
        List<Table> _tables = tables.ConvertAll(x => (Table)x).ToList();
        return _tables.Distinct().ToList().Count == tables.Count;
    }
```

Calling of these methods

```
    public bool ValidateDIPObject(DIP dip)
    {
        // Validating Tabels
        IsFilesHavingUniqueID(dip.Files);

        // Validating Files
        IsTablesHavingUniqueID(dip.Tables);

        // ... continues 
    }
```

Is there any method I can write this code in a generic way. I have to write a bunch of methods with the same pattern so I think generic code will be the best option.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply specify type and interface as generic parameters:

```
public bool IsTablesHavingUniqueID<TInterface, T>(List<TInterface> tables)
       where T:TInterface
{
    List<T> _tables = tables.ConvertAll(x => (T)x).ToList();
    return _tables.Distinct().ToList().Count == tables.Count;
}
```

This code assumes class correctly implements  `IEquatable<T>`, `GetHashCode` and
`Equals`, if not - use other overrides of `Distinct` that take comparers.

Note that code looks like partially incorrect implementation of [OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) and possibly code can be re-written as:

```
    tables.OfType<File>().Distinct().Count() == tables.Count();
```

Comment: `tables.ConvertAll(x => (T)x)` should be `tables.Cast<T>()`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Why? Code compiles as OP has `List` as input. Also I have no idea what OP is looking for. As I've noted `OfType` is more likely what they need as they seem to want to filter items of particular type (and `Cast` is less likely the right one as it simply changes type without filtering in a same way as `ConvertAll` does it)

Comment: It should be cast because a cast is being performed.  To call `ConvertAll` and then perform a cast will certainly work but to call `Cast` is better because `Cast` is for casting, i.e. changing the type of reference while still referring to the same object, and `ConvertAll` is for converting, i.e. changing the object.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I agree that `ConvertAll` is not the most expressive method here. I'd use `Where` in this case as it better expresses "filtering" intent, or if intent is "all items have given type" should   be done with `.All(x => x is File)`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I disagree on both counts. There's no mention of filtering in the question but if filtering was desired then `OfType`, which you mention in your answer, would be the appropriate option.  The use of `All` would not be of any use other than in a guarding `If` statement so you could only use it in order to throw your own exception, but I'd suggest that simply allowing `Cast` to throw an exception if an item isn't the appropriate type is more appropriate anyway.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I personally dislike both `Cast` and `OfType` because they start from untyped collection and hence you can try to cast to any type. I'd go with `.Select(x=>(File)x)` over `.Cast<File>()` as first one will actually fail at compile time if there is no way to cast one to another. (such conversion from interface to class should not be done anyway in most cases, so I really more philosophical discussion which one is more expressive in this theoretical case)

Comment: It's true that `Cast` can be called on an `IEnumerable` but if you can call `Select` then you must have an `IEnumerable<T>` anyway. You're right about using `Select` with a cast failing at compile time and `Cast` not but that doesn't help in this case and the most common use of `Cast` is specifically to convert an `IEnumerable` to an `IEnumerable<T>` in order to be able to call `Select` or the like, so you can hardly replace `Cast` with `Select` in general. As for `OfType`, given that it is intended to filter anyway, I don't see any issue as it won't throw any exception regardless.

Comment: @jmcilhinney OP started with `List<IFile>` which is `IEnumerable<IFile>` - so no particular reasons to lose type safety with call to `.Cast<File>`. (Again - I don't believe the code actually represent real use case and rather sample - so all approaches are equally valid for educational purposes)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
public bool IsUnique<IView,T>(List<IView> ls) where T : class
{
    return ls.Cast<T>().Distinct().Count()==ls.Count();
}
```